# JavaFX Button Shrinks and Loses Decoration After First Click

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

A strange behavior occured to me. I simply put a `Button` as a child of HBox. When I click for the first time, it shrinks its size and loses its own decoration as if it becomes just a plain `Label`. This behavior occurs for `Button` and those which inherits it (like `JFXButton` of Jfoenix is also affected). I animated the behavior as below:

[image: javafx button loses decoration]

It also seems that `Button` under `Toolbar` appears in this glitch state on initialization, seen as follows:

[image: javafx button glitches under toolbar]

The FXML that I'm using is as below:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" styleClass="page" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <stylesheets>
     <URL value="@../stylesheets/base.css" />
     <URL value="@../stylesheets/jfoenix.table.css" />
     <URL value="@../stylesheets/main.tasks.css" />
  </stylesheets>
  <children>
     <VBox styleClass="section" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <children>
           <Pane styleClass="section-header">
              <children>
                 <Label text="Görevler" />
              </children>
           </Pane>
           <TableView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="task-table">
              <columns>
                 <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
                 <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
              </columns>
           </TableView>
           <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
              <children>
                 <!-- This is the buggy button. -->
                 <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
              </children>
           </HBox>
        </children>
     </VBox>
  </children>
```

And these are the rules that affects this FXML file:

```
.section {
    -fx-min-width: 1000px;
    -fx-min-height: 200px;
    /*-fx-pref-width: 1000px;*/
    /*-fx-pref-height: 200px;*/

    -fx-background-color: #fff;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, #999, 10, 0.2, 0, 0);
    -fx-padding: 20px;
    -fx-spacing: 10px;
}

.section > .section-header {
    -fx-pref-height: 40px;
    -fx-max-height: 120px;
}

.section > .section-header > .label {
    -fx-font-size: 24px;
    -fx-text-fill: #666;
}

/** I've also used jfx-table-view.css of JFoenix library. **/
/** https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/wiki/Table-View **/
```

I don't know what is affecting *even* plain `Button`. What causes this glitch?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

- Java 1.8.0 162
- SceneBuilder 8.4.1
- Windows 10

### Maven Dependencies

```
org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-javafx:2.1.1
com.jfoenix:jfoenix:8.0.3
org.controlsfx:controlsfx:8.40.14
```

Comment: is it jfoenix/controlsfx only or plain fx as well?

Comment: I use JFoenix and ControlsFX together, yet in this example, I wanted to demonstrate the problem with plain JavaFX `Button` (since its visual borders are recognizable).

Comment: hmm ... never seen it, please provide a mcve (as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That effect happens because of this rule in the `jfoenix.table.css`

```css
:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-color, -fx-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-insets: -1.4, 0, 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 1.4, 0, 0;
    /*....*/
    -fx-padding: 1; /* 0.083333em; */
}
```

It actually works as intended since controls get focused when you click on them. Two buttons would make the effect clearer:

[image: Two button focused rule effect]

Comment: Thanks. I will also create an issue on [JFoenix](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) about that.